# Android programming : how to programmatically create various view types in a grid fashion

Tags: android, user-interface, grid, view

I'm not sure how to ask this question exactly, but I'll give it a try.

Here's what I'm trying to do, in one Activity.

Build a Grid, that contains [x] rows of 3 columns each, with this content

**[a TextView (containing a name)] [a Spinner (containing a list of states)] [an EditText]**

How to start ? The Views I can create programmatically, that's not a problem, I even store them in 3 array lists for later easy reference, but I can't see how to do it right.

Should I create an xml layout with e.g. (and pseudocode)

```
LinearLayout (horizontal) 
   TextView ...
   Spinner ...
   EditText ...
/LinearLayout
```

and try to inflate it in the loop I use to create each row, and setting the id of each view in a standard way (e.g. viewName[x] where x is the current "i" from my for, but is it of any use?), as we do for example for an ExpendableList Adapter's groups/childs ?

Or is there a way to actually use a GridView/GridLayout to do that (in this case, being in my Activity, how do I put each specific created View into the correct GridView/GridLayout) ?

Or still another way I don't suspect at all ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: watch the first 13min of this video. It shows very nicely about adapters: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA (he says everything for ListView, but GridView is the same.

Comment: can you post your code ? Do you want to add views programatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add views programatically then, just create a layout.xml with 3 Linearlayouts(horizontal) in it. Also assign id to those LinearLayouts. Then in your java code, just find the views and call addView() on those LinearLayouts.

Example:

```
LinearLayout ll_1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
LinearLayout ll_2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout2);
LinearLayout ll_3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout3);

...

ll_1.addView(new TextView(this));
ll_1.addView(new Spinner(this));
ll_1.addView(new EditText(this));
...
```

In detail, say for example, if i want to add spinner to LinearLayout, programatically then,

You need to get layout

```
LinearLayout linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.layoutID);
```

Create spinner as below:

```
   Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);

spinner .setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerList);
                spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Then add spinner to view

```
linearLayout.addView(spinner);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good starting point. I've still got to resolve the way my Layouts work together in order to build this list of "rows", but it's moving forward ;)